# ASP.NET Core Application Logs Not Written To Blob in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage

I've enabled application logging to a blob for an app service on Azure.

- I can view the logs in the log stream from the Azure portal
- I can see that a file like `xxxxx-#####.applicationLog.csv` is being created each hour in the Azure storage account I created, but this file doesn't actually contain the my application logs
- I tried enabling Web Server logging to storage on the same account, and that did work - I could see the logs for HTTP requests in a different file
- I tried creating a new storage account and pointing to it for the logs, but it didn't change anything

Configuration details:

- The app uses ASP.NET Core 2, running on .NET Framework 4.6.1
- I configure logging in `Program.cs` via: `.ConfigureLogging(log => log.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics())` (which is apparently necessary when running on .NET Framework instead of .NET Core runtime)

In summary: No files containing my application logs are created in Azure Storage when I configure it that way in the Azure portal.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log. Make sure you've followed all the steps there. In particular pay attention to the logging level you've set. The default is "Information", so if you've been logging "Debug", then none of that is going to actually get logged.

Comment: The logging level is set to verbose.

Comment: How are you actually logging in your application?

Comment: Using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging; i.e. injecting `ILogger<Type>`

Comment: Is your app running in Azure as well or locally?

Comment: It's running in Azure. If I view the [log stream](https://i.imgur.com/JyjXLcg.png) I can see all the logs as expected, and if I FTP into the server I can see the [file created on the filesystem](https://i.imgur.com/0cPnwgT.png) (once I've enabled filesystem logging). I just can't get the application logs to show up in the Azure storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to write Application logs to Azure blob storage ,firstly we need to enable Application log and configure blob storage for it on the Azure portal.

[image]

We could following the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/26/asp-net-core-logging/) to set up logging in the Asp.net core app.

> setting up logging in an ASP.NET Core app doesn’t require much code. ASP.NET Core new project templates already setup some basic logging providers with this code in the Startup.Configure method:

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging")); 
loggerFactory.AddDebug();
```

I also do demo for it. It works correctly on my side.

1.In the Sartup.cs file add the following code

```
 loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(
                new AzureAppServicesDiagnosticsSettings
                {
                    OutputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} [{Level}] {RequestId}-{SourceContext}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",

                }
            );
```

2.add following code in the HomeController.cs

```
 private readonly ILogger _logger;
 public HomeController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {
     _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HomeController>();
 }

 public IActionResult Index()
 {
    _logger.LogInformation("Log information");
    _logger.LogError("Logger error");
    return View();
 }
```

[image]

3.Visit the home/index page and check it from the Azure storage blob. Last section of log blob name. Defaults to "**applicationLog.txt**". We also could set it  ourselves.

[image]

Comment: It seems like the issue was that I was calling AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics() in `Program.cs` instead of `Startup.cs`. Not sure why this project didn't work in that configuration since I have other .Net Core 2 App Services setup that way, but oh well. Thanks!

Comment: @Zout can the logs be saved to a csv not a txt ? in other words can the logs be saved in a block blob not append blob?