# Logging only works localy, but not when deployed to Microsoft Azure App Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

i am facing a strange problem while developing an asp.net core application which is deployed to Microsoft Azure and runs there as an app-service. I target the full .net framework.
I am using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` and the logs are working locally without a problem, but when deploying it to Microsoft Azure there are no logs at all. The LogStream windows stays empty and just shows the `No new Trace in the last n minutes` output.

Things I already checked:

- Enabled Diagnostic Logs in the App-Service Settings
- Set the LogLevel there to Verbose
- Checked the LogFiles directory on the App-Service

Part of my appsettings.json

```
"Logging": {
 "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Information"
}
```

I am then injecting the Logger instances to the controllers like this:

```
ILogger<FooBarClassName> myLogger;

public FooBarClassName(ILogger<FooBarClassName> logger)
{
        myLogger = logger;
        ....
}
```

And use it like this:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    ...
    myLogger.LogInformation("Some Log Message");
    ...
}
```

Thanks for any help to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the logging folder on the Azure App Service? If I remember correctly, you should have writing permissions on `D:\Home` folder. Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947739/azure-app-service-write-to-filesystem-asp-net-web-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refer to the [following steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49111671/where-does-the-asp-net-core-logging-api-as-default-store-logs) to check whether you add ILogger correctly.

**Step 1**:

Go to `Startup.cs`, inside `Configure` method add following signature.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
```

The `ILoggerFactory` is default injected into the class by asp.net core.

**Setp 2**:

Set up provider.

```
loggerFactory.AddDebug();
loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
```

The `AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics` comes from the [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices).

**Setp 3**:

Example in my HomeController and the `appsettings.json` is same with you:

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        void SomeMethod()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("some log message.");
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            SomeMethod();
            return View();
        }
```

**Step 4**:

Set diagnostic logs to turn on applicaiton  logging

[image]

**Step 5**:

See logs in Log Stream

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977129/asp-net-core-application-logs-not-written-to-blob-in-azure-app-service/47009395#47009395) and this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Unbelievable :) The point was the switch from .net core to .net47 since i need to add a reference to to Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices then. Your line `loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();` pointed me to the right path. thanks alot!

Comment: Maybe you could add this information that the package needs to be added in .net full then i can accept the answer of you :)

Comment: Glad to see it helps you to solve problem. I edit the reply you could refer to.